# Is this a bug in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

The `ContourPlot[]` function has a feature which allows it to overlay contours of two different functions on one plot.  Unfortunately, the `Contours` option which controls how many contours are plotted seems to be ignored when plotting contours for two functions at once.  Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Example:

The code below draws four contour plots in a 2x2 grid. The top rows show behaviour I expect. The bottom plots show behaviour I don't expect.

[image: grid of plots, with bottom right plot not behaving as expected]

The successful plots in the top row show (as expected) single-function contour plots, with the left hand plot having only one contour, and the right-hand plot having 20 contours. Good.

I would have expected a reasonable implementation to make the plots in the bottom row be two-contour-at-a-time versions of the plots in the upper row. However, while the one on the left is as expected, the one on the right does not have an increased number of contours, despite 20 of them being requested.  For some reason, the `Contours->20` option is ignored when two functions are plotted at once.

I have tried replacing `Contours->20` with things like `Contours->{20,20}`, in case the intention is that the different overlaid contour plots can have different numbers of contours that need to be separately specified, but to no avail. And I have tried many other things.

I know I can work around this apparent deficiency by creating two separate single-function contour plots, and then overlaying them with the `Show[]` function.  This can be done and works. However, in this question I am specifically trying to understand if there is a way that the `ContourPlot[]` function can perform what seems to be a reasonable task natively, because there are circumstances where it's much nicer to use native features of functions rather than to have to create complex nesting and helper functions to (e.g.) keep plotting ranges in overlaid plots in synch.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Here is the code for you to play with:

```
onePlot[n_] := ContourPlot[{Re[f[x + I y]]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
  Contours -> n, ContourShading -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}];

twoPlots[n_] := 
 ContourPlot[{Re[f[x + I y]], Im[f[x + I y]]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 
   4},  Contours -> n];

f[z_] := Sin[z] + \[Pi] z^2/3 + z/2; 
GraphicsGrid[{
  {onePlot[1], onePlot[20]},
  {twoPlots[1], twoPlots[20]}}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I would not consider this as a bug because it behaves as stated in the documentation. If you look at the usages for [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html), there are four of them. The first one is ``ContourPlot[f]`` with one function for which you can manually specify contour values. But there is no such usage as ``ContourPlot[{f, g}]``! There is only usage with two _equations_: ``ContourPlot[{f1 == g1, f2 == g2}]``.

Comment: Therefore, writing ``ContourPlot[{f, g}]`` actually should not work because it is undocumented! However, it does work by getting silently converted to ``ContourPlot[{f == 0, g == 0}]``. In this case then, obviously, you cannot manually set the contours anymore.

Comment: @Domen : Thank you for your comments.  I'll grant you have put your finger on the button here.  I must admit that when I looked at the documentation I saw the example in the `ContourPlot` documentation entitled "Plot several equations:" I may have mis-interpreted it as meaning "Plot several functions:". I would argue that this is an entirely forgivable mistake to make as the whole point of `ContourPlot` ought to be to plot contours of functions, because it's functions that have contours, not logical expressions.  An equation plotter should be have a name like `LocusPlot` or `SolutionPlot`.

Comment: If there were a way of accepting @Domen's comment as an answer I would do so.

Comment: With "13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)", I cannot reproduce the plot shown in the question.  I am not talking about the omission of `ContourShading -> False, ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}` in the expression for `twoPlots`, but instead error messages and the generation by `twoPlots` of literally two plots..

Comment: @bbgodfrey : I was using mathematica 12 version 12.3.0.0 on Mac OS X x86 (64-bit). I have just re-checked that I see the same effect I posted by pasting the code from this post into my laptop in a fresh empty notebook and running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not consider this as a bug but as an undocumented feature.

There are four documented usages for [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html):

```
ContourPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]

ContourPlot[f == g, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]

ContourPlot[{f1 == g1, f2 == g2, …}, {x,xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]

ContourPlot[…, {x,y} ∈ reg]
```

As you can see, you can either provide *one* function or (one or more) *equations*. There is no usage with two functions: `ContourPlot[{f, g}]`, so this should not work at all! However, providing two functions does indeed work, but it gets (silently) converted to two equations: `ContourPlot[{f == 0, g == 0}]`. In this case, then, you cannot manually set the contours because it doesn't make sense anymore.

To achieve two overlaying `ContourPlot`s, use `Show`.

```
f[z_] := Sin[z] + π z^2/3 + z/2;
onePlot[f_, n_, color_] := 
  ContourPlot[f, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> n, 
   ContourShading -> False, ContourStyle -> {{Thick, color}}];

Show[onePlot[Re[f[x + I y]], 5, Blue], onePlot[Im[f[x + I y]], 15, Red]]
```

[image: ContourPlot]

---

Side note: For your particular example with a complex function, you can also use `ComplexPlot`.

```
ComplexPlot[f[z], {z, 4}, ColorFunction -> (White &), Mesh -> {5, 15},
  MeshFunctions -> {Re[#2] &, Im[#2] &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Comment: `ComplexContourPlot[{Re@f[z], Im@f[z]}, {z, -4 - 4 I, 4 + 4 I}, ContourStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Red]}]` also works well.