# Why can't this code draw the image of the equation?

Tags: plotting

```
ClearAll["`*"]
eq = {(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 4, (x - 6)^2 + (y - 6)^2 == 9}
line = SubtractSides[eq[[1]], eq[[2]]] // FullSimplify
eqs = {eq[[1]], eq[[2]], line}
ContourPlot[{eqs}, {x, -1, 20}, {y, -1, 15}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[eqs, LegendLayout -> "Column"], Below], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.`, 0.04`}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

Only plane rectangular coordinate system is displayed after operation

Comment: `Evaluate@{eqs}` ? Include the output of `$Version` to your post please as this behavior may be different with different versions.

Comment: @Syed interesting. I wonder now why my output gives something else. May be I should delete it until I find why. Your output looks more reasonable for me. hum... I just changed   `A==B` to `A-B`

Comment: The output I see on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 is two circles and a line. That's why I asked the OP to include the version info.

Comment: @Nasser, providing a list of _functions_ (not equations) to ``ContourPlot`` is [not documented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275319/75628), and it was parsed as {f1 ==0, f2 == 0, ...} until version 13. In version 13, ``ContourPlot`` has been updated, so now it seems that it parses differently, and it doesn't plot only the f==0 contours, but contours for various values of functions (that's why you get multiple contours for each function).

Comment: @Domen Ah! very interesting. I did not know all of this. So may be if I have asked for only ONE contour line to be displayed, I would have got the same output as it gives  using the trick by Syed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that "ContourPlot" has the attribute "HoldAll". Therefore, "eqs" is not evaluated. Add "Evaluate, then you will get a plot:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqs], {x, -1, 20}, {y, -1, 15}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[eqs, LegendLayout -> "Column"], Below], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.`, 0.04`}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]